# Testing Java enhanced for loop with Mockito for code coverage

Tags: junit, mockito, code-coverage

I am trying to test enhanced for loop for code coverage but in vain. I have tried various methods but none is able to pass the for loop for code coverage. I have failed. Need some help / advise.

Below is the code snippet

```
Page<Blob> folderList = storage.list
                    (this.bucketName,        
                    Storage.BlobListOption.prefix(this.inputFolder),        
                    Storage.BlobListOption.currentDirectory());

private Set<String> getFolders(Page<Blob> folderList) {  
    Set<String> folder = new HashSet<>();  
    for (Blob blob : folderList.iterateAll()) {    
        String folderName = blob.getName().replace(this.inputFolder, StringUtils.EMPTY);    
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(folderName)        
            && folderName.endsWith("/")        
            && folderName.matches(".*\\d.*")) {      
            folder.add(folderName.replace("/", StringUtils.EMPTY));    
            }  
    }  
    return folder;
}
```

Below is the snippet of test case.

I have tried various options:

```
// Option 1:
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob_name");
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));

Iterable<Blob> mockIterable = Mockito.mock(Iterable.class);
when(folderList.iterateAll()).thenReturn(mockIterable);
Iterator<Blob> mockIterator = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
when(mockIterable.iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(blob);

// Option 2

Blob mockedBlob = Mockito.mock(Blob.class);
when(folderList.iterateAll()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(mockedBlob));
```

It's not going inside the for loop in either of the options, although my test cases are passing. My basic purpose is code coverage and if it doesn't get inside the for loop then the coverage decreases moreover, the values returned by this method is used by the other method.

I am badly stuck. Please help. Please let me know if any more information is required.